# Is there an equivalent of the C/C++ #line directive in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, debugging

The C/C++ preprocessors insert `#line` directives so that error messages and debuggers can refer to the original source line.  R also copied this kind of directive.  Is there an equivalent of this for Javascript?

I'd like to concatenate several source files together so that the web page only loads one script file, but when using a debugger in a browser, I would like error messages to refer to the original source files.  Is this possible?

For example, I might have two source files:

`file1.js`:

```
getfield <- function(x) {
  x.field;
};
```

`file2.js`:

```
x = {feild: 1};  // typo in field name
console.log(getfield(x));
```

I want to put these together into one file:

`both.js`:

```
#line 1 "file1.js"
getfield <- function(x) {
  x.field;
};

#line 1 "file2.js"
x = {feild: 1};  // typo in field name
console.log(getfield(x));
```

so that the reported missing field error is shown as being on `file1.js#2`, called from `file2.js#2`.  Of course, `both.js` generates a syntax error on the `#line` lines, but I'm hoping there's some equivalent that's legal.

Comment: Generating a sourcemap will insert similar directives.

Comment: @VLAZ:  yes, that looks like what I want.  Now I just need to work out how to generate the sourcemap.